# How to log to a file from an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, logback, slf4j

I can't log to a file from my eclipse rcp application.

So, I followed the guide on https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLogging/article.html.

I installed Logback SLF4J Binding, logback classic module and logback core module from orbit repository.

I created a plugin that read the config file logback.xml. That plugin require ch.qos.logback.classic & ch.qos.logback.core. I also imported org.sl4j.
I imported org.slf4j on the other plugins.

Here is the logback.xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />  

    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="d://logFiles/app.log"/>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -FILE- %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -OUT- %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="fr.test.sirius.logger" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

When I launch my Eclipse RCP application with "run as" everything is working as attended.
When I create an update site and install the feature on Eclipse, the log file is not created. I tried to launch eclipse with -console argument, the logs are printed correctly in the OSGi console.

edit: The logs are not printed correctly in the OSGI console, seems like an issue with the activator.

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured the start levels as shown in the tutorial? Is the plug-in Activator running when the RCP starts?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, the logs in the osgi console are not formatted as the logback.xml specify.
The start levels is set to 3.

Comment: I tried to set the start level to 2. I also added the bin folder of the plugin in the build configuration, the logback.xml was already there.

Comment: So on a fresh installation of the feature, if I stop then start the plugin logging.config that load logback.xml, everything works even when I restart Eclipse. But I would like to not have to manually restart the plugin once.